# compile error: end sub expected on ActiveDocument.Close after .VBComponents("thisDocument").CodeModule.AddFromFile

Tags: vba, ms-word

Even after looking through all of similar phrased questions and several search engine results I did not find any answer.

I copy the current word document and change the codebase by removing former modules and rewrite the ThisDocument-component by adding from file. For the context, but most probably skippable:

```
Public Sub DOCMPublish()
   '...msoFileDialogSaveAs...and then...'

    Application.Documents.Add ThisDocument.FullName
    On Error Resume Next
    
    ' unlink fields and finalize content to avoid updates within the archived documents
    Dim oFld As field
    For Each oFld In ActiveDocument.Fields
        oFld.Unlink
    Next
        
    ' rewrite macros and unload modules
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim Element As Object
    For Each Element In ActiveDocument.VBProject.VBComponents
        ActiveDocument.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove Element
    Next
    rewriteMain ActiveDocument, "ThisDocument", ThisDocument.path & "\Document_Public_DOCM.vba"
    ' protect content
    ActiveDocument.Protect wdAllowOnlyFormFields, Password:="LoremIpsum"
    
    ' msoFileDialogSaveAs does not support filetypes, hence forcing extension
    DOCMFile = fileSaveName.SelectedItems(1)
    DOCMFile = Replace(DOCMFile, ".doc", ".docm")
    DOCMFile = Replace(DOCMFile, ".docmx", ".docm")
    
    ' the next line saves the copy to your location and name
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 filename:=DOCMFile, FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocumentMacroEnabled
    ' next line closes the copy leaving you with the original document
    ActiveDocument.Close
End Sub
```

This sub worked properly for that over the last years:

```
Sub rewriteMain(ByRef Workument, ByVal Module, ByVal Source)
    'delete code from ThisDocument/ThisWorkbook
    Workument.VBProject.VBComponents.Item(1).CodeModule.DeleteLines 1, Workument.VBProject.VBComponents.Item(1).CodeModule.CountOfLines
    'rewrite from file
    With Workument.VBProject
            .VBComponents(Module).CodeModule.AddFromFile Source
    End With
    'delete module
    Workument.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove Workument.VBProject.VBComponents("Rewrite")
End Sub
```

The content of *Document_Public_DOCM.vba* to be imported is

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Document_Close()
    ThisDocument.Saved = True
End Sub

Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal ContentControl As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim cc As ContentControl
    For Each cc In ThisDocument.ContentControls
        'checkboxes have no type attribute to check against, therefore the need of _
        error handling on checked-property that is checkbox-only in this usecase
        On Error Resume Next
        ThisDocument.Bookmarks("text" & cc.Tag).Range.Font.Hidden = Not cc.Checked
        ThisDocument.Bookmarks("notext" & cc.Tag).Range.Font.Hidden = cc.Checked
    Next
End Sub
```

I can see no problem here, and the modified and saved file doesn't complain later on. But in the meantime i get the compiling error on closing the ActiveDocument after the import and ActiveDocument.SaveAs2. I get no error without closing the file though, but this is not nice for the work environment, messing up the screen.

Often word crashes, sometimes it just results in a state loss. I also tried encoding as utf-8 and iso 8859-1, disabled screen updating but that does not seem to be the solution as well. What am I missing?

Edit:
What I tried further without success:

- disabling syntax checking in the editor
- On Error Resume Next
- Err.Clear
- newDoc.EnableEvents = False (after implementing @Алексей-Р suggestion)
- excluding deletion of .VBProject.VBComponents names "ThisDocument"

Also explicitly compiling the modified files code expectedly does not raise any errors. Are there any editor settings I am unaware of?

Comment: I tried your code on MS Word 2019 on Windows 10 and could not reproduce the problem you wrote about. One potential problem I saw was the use of `ActiveDocument`. Since you didn't publish all the code, some operations could change `ActiveDocument` and do something on the wrong book. Try binding the book to the variable `Dim newDOC As Document: Set newDOC = Documents.Add(ThisDocument.FullName)` and then use `newDOC.` instead of `ActiveDocument.`

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately this did not solve the problem. I run it on office 2016 on win10. Since this obviously looks like good practice I implemented it anyway. Tried some other things as stated in the edit...

Comment: tested it with ofgice 2019 with same results. used libraries are visual basic for applications, ms word 16.0 object library, ole automation, ms office 16.0 office library and ms forms 2.0 object library. do you have additional libaries enabled?

Comment: Here are all the references: `(VBA)Visual Basic For Applications[Type Library], (Word)Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library[Type Library], (stdole)OLE Automation[Type Library], (Normal)[Project], (Office)Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library[Type Library]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to answer it myself, <del>at least this solved the issue in this case:</del>

I open the file with

```
Set newDOC = Documents.Add(ThisDocument.FullName, True, wdNewBlankDocument, False)
```

I can only assume that opening the file in a new blank document and not displaying it might prevent the code executing and therefore having issues being replaced at runtime.

Edit:
it worked at first, then it didn't. Still don't know why. The following now seems to be failproof:

```
Set newDOC = Documents.Add("", True, wdNewBlankDocument, False)

ThisDocument.Content.Copy
dim rng
Set rng = newDoc.Content
rng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
rng.Paste
'clear clipboard, otherwise an annoying msg popy up everytime because huge content is left there from copying
Dim clscb As New DataObject 'object to use the clipboard
clscb.SetText text:=Empty
clscb.PutInClipboard 'put void into clipboard
```

This solution opens a new blank document and copypasts the content without having macros in the first place. Afterwards I proceed to rewrite the modules as in the initial snippet from the question

Not sure why it worked for @АлексейР with my provided code though. Thanks for caring anyway!